# Style elements in html page to adjust dynamically depending on the size of the screen

Tags: css, height, styling

Hey guys I am building a web chat and my first objective is to put together the html page. I am using the BootStrap 3 grid, so whenever I resize the width of the screen my elements adjust accordingly to the size of the screen. However, the BootStrap grid does not work when I resize the height of the screen, hence my button is cut off and I cannot figure out a way to solve this. I tried using a library from git hub (https://gist.github.com/metaist/7632393), but it did not solve my issue either...

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row" id="top-div">
            <!-- The users username -->
            <h1 class="text-primary">Placeholder Username</h1>
        </div>


        <div class="row" id="chat-and-users">
            <div class="form-group" id="middle-div">
                <div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9 bg-info" id="chat-column">
                        <!-- Chat Column -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 bg-success" id="users-column">
                        <!-- Users Column -->
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row" id="bottom-div">
            <form action="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" id="message-input" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a message...">
                </div>   
                <button type="submit" id="button-send" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
}

#chat-and-users{
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #202020;
}

#chat-column{
    height: 80vh;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-right: 1px solid #202020;
}

#users-column{
    height: 80vh;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-left: 1px solid #202020;
} 

#bottom-div {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

This is how my page looks, notice that I cannot see the entire button even if I reduce my doc (My apps) to the minimum size...

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I want the h1 to take 10% of the page, the blue/green rectangles 80% of the page (hence why I gave them a height of 80 vh), and the input/button form 10% of the page. Any form of help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```
html, body, .container {
    height: 100%;
}

#top-div, #bottom-div {
    height: 10%;
}

#chat-and-users {
    height: 80%;
}
```

And remove `height: 80vh` from `#chat-column` and `#users-column`

`vh` is relative to your `viewport`. That's why it's not changing when you resize the window. `%`, on the other hand, is relative to the parent element, in this case `body`, which has a height of `100%` now

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, I originally attempted this. The problem is that the parent of chat-column and user-column is a div and not body, hence it did not work. I will upload a picture in my post, so that you see what happens when I implement your suggestion.

Comment: Hey @ceferrari, it did not work. I also tried both a height of 80% and 100% for the height of chat-and-users. I have uploaded a picture in the original question.

Comment: Yes I did, let me rewrite in a clean version

Comment: Updated my answer again. The updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y7sw43d2/. Deleting my old comments

Comment: I just opened the jsfiddle, and I can still cut off the button and input in jsfiddle. Also I cannot see the blue and green rectangles on jsfiddle. Is this what you are seeing?

Comment: Same with your new version. Also I appreciate you taking time out of your day to help me solve this :)

Comment: Yes but that's the expected behavior because we set `100%` on `html` and `body` and fiddle result's window share space with css window. It should look ok on a regular website

Comment: I added a new picture, with your changes. If you pay close attention to top border of the rectangle, you can see a bit of blue and green.

Comment: From the screenshot, it seems that `#chat-and-users` has `height: 100%`. It should be `80%`. Either that or you still have the `height` selector in either `#chat-column` or `#users-column` or both of them

Comment: It looks 100% but in jsfiddle and in my solution, they are both 80%

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159356/discussion-between-ceferrari-and-frankg26).

Comment: Thanks a lot ceferrari. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with setting the header and footer height to 10vh is that when the viewport is short their content may exceed that height, as is the case in your screenshot.

May I suggest a different approach: Give the header and footer a fixed height, and scale the  columns to fill the remaining available space:

```
#top-div,
#bottom-div {
    /* change this to whatever you want */
    height: 100px;
}
#chat-column,
#users-column {
    /* viewport height minus combined height of header & footer  */
    height: calc(100vh - 200px); 
}
```

Comment: I like where you are going @Jonathan Nicol, adjusting the rectangles based on top-div and bottom-div. However, it does not solve the resizing issue. Would you have a suggestion for the height of top-div and bottom-div

Comment: What is the "resizing issue" you need to solve? If it helps to visualize how my solution scales, here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fomunnq5/ You would obviously need to change the height values for header and footer to suit your needs.

Comment: the resizing issue is that my button and input form is cut off whenever I adjust the height of the screen. The jsfiddle you shared also has this issue with the red border, if I adjust the height the bottom border is no longer visible

Comment: Are you saying that when you adjust the height of the viewport while viewing my jsfiddle, that the footer is cut off? If so, can you tell me which browser you observe this behaviour in.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the behaviour describe. Assuming that you have not changed any values in the Fiddle, the header, footer and content columns should always be contained within the viewport, unless you make the viewport really really short (less than 200 pixels tall).

Comment: No worries Jonathan, I am going to start working on functionality now. Since Ive spend a good amount of hours trying to figure this out. Your help is much appreciated.